# setting socket-timeout not seems to be effective when making jdbc connection

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sqljdbc

I need to set the `socketTimeout` property when establishing the connection from database using jdbc. I am using `sqljdbc4` to connect with SQL SERVER 2008 R2. Here is my code.

```
java.util.Properties info = new java.util.Properties();
info.setProperty("user", informationStoreDefinition.getProperties().get(USER));
info.setProperty("password", informationStoreDefinition.getProperties().get(PASSWORD));
info.setProperty("socketTimeout", "10");
info.setProperty("loginTimeout", "10");
testConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(informationStoreDefinition.getProperties().get(DB_URL), info);
```

I did not find the socket timeout effective in my case. I have set it for 10 seconds but it throws time-out after 30 seconds. I will set the time out to 30 seconds but that need to work at 10 seconds first.

Comment: Socket timeout only applies to reads after connecting, it doesn't apply to the connect itself. You need to find a connect timeout setting (I'm not sure if it exists or not for SQL Server).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes it has a `connectTimeout` setting and I tried it also. It thrown an Exception - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: `The TCP/IP connection to the host xxx.xxx.x.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.` and it takes 30 seconds even I set it to 5 sec.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/

Comment: That site lists _"connection string properties for the ADO.NET SqlConnection object"_, in other words it is for C#, not for the SQL Server JDBC driver.